# Authenticate Custom App(Voice App) in Google Assistant

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I want to Login into my custom application that is using the voice user interface.

Explanation:
We can link a netflix account with google home, similarly how can I link my custom application which needs to get authenticated before using it. What is the way to allow authentication on your app through voice (provided there is no Account linking but a custom userIds & passwords stored within the database of that application)

Eg: UserId : BPU/12045
    Password : 12bpu

Ok Google talk to my App, then google assistant can ask for authentication and maintaining the session (speaking your id password may not be the best way). What is the best way to do that?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AoG supports [Account Linking](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/) to maintain user sign in and sessions.

You can choose if you just want to support your own user with OAuth, or want to support sign up for new users with voice with [Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in) (or both).

[Here is an article](https://medium.com/@hitherejoe/authenticating-users-with-actions-on-google-31083b12381a) by Joe Birch explaining account linking setup.

Comment: How can I give an option to unlink those accounts to user?

Comment: Users can unlink their account in the Actions Assistant Directory page.